# Column "migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial"

Tags: postgresql, laravel, migration

I am using PostgreSQL for my project but I get this error when I migrate process.

```
aldebaran@aldebaran-SATELLITE-L50-C:/var/www/html/CRMPixel$ php artisan migrate

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR: Column "migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial". (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null, "migration" varchar(191) not null, "batch" integer not null))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR: Column "migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Show us the migration.

Comment: @user3158900 version : PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1430

Comment: @Don'tPanic https://hizliresim.com/RO6J97

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Redshift PostgreSQL doesn't support `serial` type: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html)

> These PostgreSQL data types are not supported in Amazon Redshift.
>
> - Arrays
> - BIT, BIT VARYING
> - BYTEA
> - Composite Types
> - Date/Time Types
>
>   - INTERVAL
>   - TIME
> - Enumerated Types
> - Geometric Types
> - JSON
> - Network Address Types
> - Numeric Types
>
>   - SERIAL, BIGSERIAL, SMALLSERIAL
>   - MONEY
> - Object Identifier Types
> - Pseudo-Types
> - Range Types
> - Text Search Types
> - TXID_SNAPSHOT
> - UUID
> - XML

`$table->increments('id')` produces a `serial` field.

Instead of this use i.e. [laravel-sequence](https://packagist.org/packages/bnbwebexpertise/laravel-sequence):

```
$table->unsignedInteger('id')->primary()
```

Comment: Well, I don't know I do not know where I'm using the serial, what's the serial in laravel ? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I keep getting the same mistake. Migration ScreenShot : https://ibb.co/i4V8UQ